# jquery draggable containment not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I recently made a new function to create draggable dialogs and keeping them in the content DIV of the CMS. The selector would be: #CMS_content #content. I use this as my draggable function:

```
$('#' + id).draggable({
    handle: '.title',
    containment: 'window'
});
```

This works as expected: the dialog doesn't go out of the screen. The dialog is custom made and not any dialog of jQueryUI.

However, if I use the selector (see code below) to keep it in the content ID, whenever I drag the window it goes out of the screen on the top. So I drag the dialog, it 'disappears', but when I open firebug, it's just placed outside the window.

```
$('#' + id).draggable({
    handle: '.title',
    containment: '#CMS_content #content' // <-- not working.
});
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work? I think it's a way better idea to keep it in the content rather than making it draggable over the side menu and top header.

This is the HTML of the dialog:

```
<div id="draggableDialog" class="dialog onfront">
    <div class="title">
        This is a title
        <img src="images/delete_icon.png">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is content
    </div>
</div>
```

The HTML is added to #CMS_content #content, so the full HTML would be:

```
<body>
    <div id="CMS_content">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="draggableDialog" class="dialog onfront">
                <div class="title">
                    This is a title
                    <img src="images/delete_icon.png">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    This is content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Added HTML of the dialog.

Comment: Please add the rendered `html` so that we create a `demo` and try our best to resolve..

Comment: I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: draggableDialog is the id, forgot to change.

Comment: Yes that's correct. With some dialogs you want a scroll bar and it wouldn't work very nice.

Comment: I believe you. #CMS_content has position relative and #content has position absolute. The dialog has position fixed (.dialog). I don't think box-shadow has anything to do with it neither height and width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the `CSS` you specified in comments, if you add `height` and `width` to your `#content` then you can actually see the `element` inside the container while dragging with the same `js` you have.

```
#CMS_content #content
{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:yellow;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ewjg9w0y/1/)**

Comment: I have never had the width and height on the #content and it worked before. There's a height for the CMS_content (765px) and width (100%).

Comment: But see **[this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ewjg9w0y/2/)**. Implemented your `CSS` plus specified `height` and `width` for `#content` as `100%`.. So without that I think its difficult to get `height` and `width` set for `element` with `position:absolute`

Comment: I did use some px width and height and now I can still drag it out of the #content. It stays in the whole document though (same as window containment)

Comment: Can you update the fiddle I provided with your code and give the link back to me?

Comment: Nevermind, found out I tested the wrong page. Setting the width and height on the #content did solve the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)